# Vite recognizes link with sass on npm run build, but not on npm run dev

Tags: vue.js, vite

I am using a `<link>` tag to import a SASS/SCSS in the Vite/VueJS 3 index file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="sass" href="/src/assets/test.scss">
```

The thing is it works very well when I run `npm run build`: the SCSS is converted into CSS, merged in the generated files and applied to the page as expected.

But when I run `npm run dev`, if I look at the page source code it simply outputted that `<link ...>` tag *as-is* to the browser.

This is my entire `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="sass" href="/src/assets/test.scss">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tested more than one SCSS and it is not due to error in that file. For the sake of simplicity, this is a very small sample of valid SCSS `test.scss` that should affect the entire page:

```css
body{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Why does it work on build, but does not work in dev (HRM)?

Comment: Did you try to use a relative path instead of absolute one ?

Comment: I tried some paths with `@` and `~`, and without slash. It keeps outputting the link element instead and browser ignore its because it does not recognize the language. Is that link something that should work? My confusion is why it works on build. I would be happy if that did not work at all.

Comment: I do not really know. Only recently migrated from Webpack to Vite and still learning. What I know is that Vue CLI (and webpack) always treated absolute paths (starting with `/xxx`) as something "not to process" - which makes sense in the Web world. So when working with filesystem (and assets meant to be processed by a bundler) it feels better to explicitly use a relative path ie. `./src/....`

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and error, it seems that the link element is not correctly compiled by the `dev` (HRM) mode, even if production build works.

It may be realted to Webpack, as a more traditional way works for both, dev and build.

The solution is to create a script of "module" type and import the file there:

```html
<script type="module">
  import "/src/assets/test.scss";
</script>
```

Now it gets compiled in both versions.

It works even with a shorter version of the same process:

```html
<script type="module" src="/src/assets/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"></script>
```

Though the question "Why does it work on build, but does not work in dev (HRM)?" remains unanswered here.